# Perl XPath: use "and" to return two nodes

Tags: xml, perl, xpath

```
<pets>
  <dog>woof</dog>
  <cow>moo</cow>
  <bird>chirp</bird>
</pets>
```

I'm using `XML::LibXML`, version 1.0, and I want to only return the nodes if **both** XPath expressions (conditions) are met.

If I use the vertical `or` bar `|` , this XPath expression will work:

`//dog[.="woof"] | //bird[.="chirp"]` <-- returns both nodes

...but since it's an "or", if only one matches, it will return the 1 matching node.

e.g. - `//dog[.="xwoof"] | //bird[.="chirp"]` <-- will return just matching `bird` node.

It's all or nothing - I want to only return if both match, like this:

`//dog[.="woof"] and //bird[.="chirp"]`

...but it doesn't accept an "and" condition, nor `&`.

What would be the XPath syntax to return both nodes for both conditions to be met?

I want only the matching `dog` and `bird` elements, and no mention of `pets`.

Comment: **Rollback reason:**   Two days, three answers, and eight answer upvotes have transpired since you posted your question.  Your update substantially changes the originally posted and answered question.   Please accept whichever answer to your original question helped you the most, and then if you wish to get *new* answers based on your *new* example, post a ***new question***.  Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

```xml
//*[ dog="woof" and bird="chirp" ]/*[ self::dog="woof" or self::bird="chirp" ]
```

or

```xml
//dog[ .="woof" and ../bird="chirp" ] |
//bird[ .="chirp" and ../dog="woof" ]
```

---

**Option 1** - Look down approach

Let's start by assuming you want to return the `pets` element. For that, we can use the following:

```xml
//*[ dog="woof" and bird="chirp" ]
```

[Results](http://xpather.com/nlYZzS13)

`[...]` can be thought of WHERE clause. The above returns `pets` elements WHERE `dog="woof" and bird="chirp"` is true.

The following would also work (WHERE `dog="woof"` is true, and WHERE `bird="chirp"` is true):

```xml
//*[dog="woof"][bird="chirp"]
```

[Results](http://xpather.com/3XB9ay1j)

We can customize this to return other thing by adding to it.

```xml
//*[ dog="woof" and bird="chirp" ]/( dog[.="woof"] | bird[.="chirp"] )
```

[Results](http://xpather.com/RximbfRU)

As you can see, `|` is the *union* operator which combines two sets of nodes.

One problem. That syntax is not supported by XML::LibXML since libxml2 only supports XPath 1.0. A small adjustment can be made to compensate.

```xml
//*[ dog="woof" and bird="chirp" ]/*[ self::dog="woof" or self::bird="chirp" ]
```

[Results](http://xpather.com/Gc3E64Qr)

---

**Option 2** - Look up/around approach

Another way to phrase the previous search is: the dogs and birds that have the other as a sibling.

```xml
//dog[ .="woof" and ../bird="chirp" ] |
//bird[ .="chirp" and ../dog="woof" ]
```

[Results](http://xpather.com/4i0tasY1)

---

[Simplified `dog[.="woof"]` to `dog="woof"` where possible, as per @kjhughes answer.]

Comment: @CraigP, Adjusted as per the additional info you provided.

Comment: Your first expression seems to use XPath 2.0 syntax which won't work with XML::LibXML.

Comment: @nwellnhof, I agree, the //*[ dog="woof" and bird="chirp" ]/( dog[.="woof"] | bird[.="chirp"] ) is not 1.0 compatible  ... it's the 2nd half, starting with the parentheses.

Comment: I missed that you had mentioned XML::LibXML. I have adjusted my answer.

Answer (score 4):

This [XPath](http://xpather.com/qIgO8JoC),

```
//*[dog="woof" and bird="chirp"]/*[self::dog="woof" or self::bird="chirp"]
```

will select all `dog` and `bird` elements whose string values are `"woof"` and `"chirp"`, respectively, and that exist within a common parent element:

```
<dog>woof</dog>
<bird>chirp</bird>
```

**Credit:** @ikegami's help in interpreting OP's intent was indispensable.  Be sure to +1 his answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66284153/290085).

---

**Side note:**    `|` is a union operator (of [node-sets](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#node-sets) in XPath 1.0 and [node sequences](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-sequence-expressions) in XPath 2.0). It is not logical OR.

---

Comment: `.../*[self::dog or self::bird]` should be enough.

Comment: @nwellnhof: Only if OP is alright with also selecting, [for example](http://xpather.com/zU4YscKo), `<dog>bow</dog>` when the other `dog` and `bird` parent and string value constraints are met.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear what should be returned if there are several dogs and a bird (or vice versa).

You can first check that there are at least two nodes satisfying the conditions, then select them:

```
//*[dog[.="woof"]][bird[.="chirp"]]/*[name()="dog" and .="woof" or name()="bird" and .="chirp"]
```

(tested in [xsh](http://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-XSH2/xsh) which is great for playing with XPath expressions)

Comment: Thanks guys ...
Sorry, i only want to return the matching nodes, equal to  <dog> and <bird>, even if several matches ... but i don't want the parent node; nor do i want to specify/use the absolute "pets" path in the xpath expr to avoid returning the parent node.

I like this Choroba:
//*[dog[.="woof"]][bird[.="chirp"]]/*[name()="dog" and .="woof" or name()="bird" and .="chirp"]

Comment: Same with slight variation on 2nd selection piece:
//*[dog[.="woof"]][bird[.="chirp"]]/*[//dog[.="woof"] or //bird[.="chirp"]]

Comment: @CraipP, No, that [doesn't work](http://xpather.com/GNXrO1sh) (it includes the cow). You were going for [`//*[dog[.="woof"]][bird[.="chirp"]]/*[self::dog[.="woof"] or self::bird[.="chirp"]]`](http://xpather.com/gdha140p). My answer has something simpler.

Comment: Note that using `name` (without also checking the namespace) can cause problems (breaks the e**x**tensiblity of **X**ML)